# CSS3 Text (Word Art) Effect

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

### Background

I have not had any luck trying to figure out the name of this effect and therefore cannot find examples of how to make this look nice in CSS3.

I have searched for things related to but not exact wording: bootstrap grid layout text web designs, scaffolding, masonry, word art.  Word art seems so close that I am disappointed I cannot find this design name.

My goal is to create a header from pure css and bootstrap grid that shows the tags of the article in a neat fashion.  My artistic ability to eye this is, well not there :) so need an example please!

### Help

What is the name of this CSS styling?

### Example

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a "**word cloud**" or a "**tag cloud**".

A simple example would look like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.tagcloud
{
/*    height:300px;*/
}
.tag-1
{
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
}
.tag-2
{
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
}
.tag-3
{
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
}
.tag-4
{
    font-size: 28px; 
    color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
}
.tag-5
{
    font-size: 36px; 
    color: rgb(70, 207, 176);
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="tagcloud" class="col-10 offset-1 mt-3">
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Cookies</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Pies</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Beer</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Butter</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Coding</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Apples</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Cheese</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Hamburger</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Lunch</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Dinner</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Ice Cream</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">Steak</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">JavaScript</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">HTML</a>
            <a href="#" class="p-2">CSS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var classes = ["tag-1", "tag-2", "tag-3", "tag-4", "tag-5"];

        $("#tagcloud a").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

To adjust the padding between different tags, you could use the native Bootstrap 4 spacing classes such as `p-2` or `p-3` etc.

Comment: Note: There are 2 parts in my code snippet that are important. The custom css at the top and the custom piece of JavaScript at the very bottom.